# WebSocket cannot connect to endpoint when running Spring-Boot 2.2 with lazy bean initialization?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I'm having trouble getting the client to connect to a WebSocket endpoint when the Spring-Boot 2.2 application is started in lazy-init mode.

I was able to get [this Spring.io tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to work. It uses spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.1.6. I changed the pom.xml to use spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.2.0 and got it to work also.

But when I set `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` in application.properties, the client does not connect to the server via WebSocket anymore when I click on the "Connect" button. In Chrome Developer Tool > Network > WebSocket, I see that the client sends a CONNECT request, but it never receives a "CONNECTED" response.

I've uploaded my project file to GitHub here:
https://github.com/hirokiterashima/spring-boot-stomp-messaging-websocket. The first commit is the 'complete' directory of the original project in the Spring.io tutorial, which uses Spring-Boot 2.1.6: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/master/complete. The second commit contains my changes to pom.xml to use Spring-Boot 2.2.0 and addition of application.properties file to enable lazy initialization. As you can see, all I did in the second commit was change to Spring Boot 2.2.0, updated the jQuery webjars dependency, and enabled lazy initialization. If you comment-out the spring.main.lazy-initialization line in application.properties, it will work.

Did anybody else come across a similar issue? What can I do to make this work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: Hi, please see the edited description. Thank you.

Comment: A bug report has been raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19611

Answer (score 1):

just register the following @Bean:

```java
    @Bean
    public LazyInitializationExcludeFilter stompWebSocketHandlerMappingLazyInitializationExcludeFilter() {
        return LazyInitializationExcludeFilter.forBeanTypes(HandlerMapping.class);
    }
```

or

```java
    @Bean
    public LazyInitializationExcludeFilter stompWebSocketHandlerMappingLazyInitializationExcludeFilter() {
        return ((beanName, beanDefinition, beanType) -> beanName.equals("stompWebSocketHandlerMapping"));
    }
```